# JSON Multiple Parameters Reading using JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Hi guys I am getting issue while reading this file can anyone suggest me how to read this file by using model name and tagline and also variant code of this model. I am new to reading in json using java , whenever I am trying to read getting this exception i.e. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONArray (org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray are in unnamed module of loader 'app') Any reference for this?

```
{
  "models": {
    "IN": [
      {
        "modelName": "Inter",
        "modelTagline": "roadster",
        "models": [
          {
            "ID": "test-650",
            "engineCapacity": "Twin",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
            "mailCCBTR": "",
            "mailToBTR": "",
            "mailerBikeImageBTR": "orange.jpg",
            "modelCodeBTR": "test",
            "name": "Interc50",
            "power": "5rpm",
            "showCatalogue": true,
            "showInDealer": false,
            "showInREPrime": true,
            "tagLine": "A classic British roadster",
            "torque": "5rpm",
            "variants": [
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Canyon Red",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Canyon Red",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "ty",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Ven",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VS",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Granite ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VT",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
               "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Grey ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "60PE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Orange ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VPE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
               "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Blue",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "SVSE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl":"https://www.test.png",,
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "rgra ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "LE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png",
              }
            ],
            "webp": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp/Models/1280x853---INT.webp",
            "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp-mobile-1x/Models/1280x853---INT.webp",
            "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp-mobile-2x/Models/1280x853---INT.webp"
          }
        ]
      }
     
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid, I fixed it using https://jsonchecker.com/ and https://jsonprettier.com/

```json
{
  "models": {
    "IN": [
      {
        "modelName": "Inter",
        "modelTagline": "roadster",
        "models": [
          {
            "ID": "test-650",
            "engineCapacity": "Twin",
            "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
            "mailCCBTR": "",
            "mailToBTR": "",
            "mailerBikeImageBTR": "orange.jpg",
            "modelCodeBTR": "test",
            "name": "Interc50",
            "power": "5rpm",
            "showCatalogue": true,
            "showInDealer": false,
            "showInREPrime": true,
            "tagLine": "A classic British roadster",
            "torque": "5rpm",
            "variants": [
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Canyon Red",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Canyon Red",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "ty",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Ven",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VS",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Granite ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VT",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Grey ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "60PE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Orange ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "VPE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "Blue",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "SVSE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              },
              {
                "highlights": [
                  "It's a blast to ride on twisty back roads, highways or the urban jungle, with equal ease and grace, for novices and experienced riders alike",
                  "",
                  "",
                  ""
                ],
                "id": "test-650",
                "imageUrl": "https://www.test.png",
                "name": "Blue",
                "showBookNow": false,
                "showConfigureNow": true,
                "showInDealer": false,
                "showInREPrime": true,
                "tankColor": "rgra ",
                "tankImage": "https://www.test.png",
                "variantCode": "LE",
                "webp": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.test.png",
                "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.test.png"
              }
            ],
            "webp": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp/Models/1280x853---INT.webp",
            "webp-mobile-1x": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp-mobile-1x/Models/1280x853---INT.webp",
            "webp-mobile-2x": "https://www.royalenfield.com/node/assets/configurator-master-images/Web/webp-mobile-2x/Models/1280x853---INT.webp"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```